# Android : PublisherAdView showing empty space

Tags: android, sdk, admob, adview

I have changed my android application to include ads by using    Google play service library. When I used "Adview" to show ads its is working fine,    But when I changed it to "PublisherAdView" it is showing empty space.    What's wrong, I had done, I have been using the same ad unit id which    have been Used in the ad Mob SDK.Is it necessary to change them ? Below is the   code i had used :

```
    AdSize[] adSizes = "An array of adSizes";
      PublisherAdview adView = new PublisherAdview(activity);
      adView.setAdSizes(adSizes);
      adView.setAdUnitId("My Unit Id");
      mAdLayout.addView(adView);
      adView.setAdListener(this);
      adView.loadAd(new PublisherAdRequest.Builder()
            .addNetworkExtras(new AdMobExtras(new Bundle()))
            .build());
```

Comment: have you had the anwers?

Answer (score -1):

*PublisherAdView* is for use with Google's *DoubleClick for Publisher* (DfP) ad server. So in order to use this type of ad view, you would need to set up a DfP instance and either enter ads directly in DfP or configure it to forward ad requests to other ad networks (possibly AdMob).

In addition, the ad unit id is different for DfP. You would get a DfP specific id.